# pg_bulkload from S3 bucket

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can pg_bulkload read file from S3 bucket? Please share the scripts. Could you please tell me how do we deploy the script into production?

Comment: Is your PostgreSQL database running on Amazon RDS or EC2, or is this on your own computer?

Comment: It's on aws ec2

Comment: Amazon RDS has some capabilities to [Import data into PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html), but that would not apply to your own installation of PostgreSQL.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A. You might want to ask at: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

`pg_bulkload` cannot read data from an Amazon S3 bucket.

You could 'cheat' by using a utility that mounts an Amazon S3 as a disk (eg s3fs, Mountain Duck, Cloudberry Drive). This way, `pg_bulkload` can simply reference a 'local' disk without knowing that it is backed by Amazon S3.

Alternatively, simply download the data from S3 to your local disk and then use `pg_bulkload`.

Comment: Thanks.. Is there any other bulk load option that allows to read from S3 bucket and load to postgresql?